# How to get last truncated time for each tables in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, truncate

I have a SQL Server 2012 database. Is it possible to get last truncated time for all tables in the database?

Note: Recovery mode is `SIMPLE` in my scenario. Is it possible if I change it to `FULL` ?

Answer (score 11):

Remember that truncate is an [efficiently logged operation](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-1930-truncate-table-is-non-logged/).

Since you are running in Simple Recovery mode and provided your T-log is not truncated, you can get it using undocumented `fn_dblog`:

```
SELECT [Current LSN]
    ,[Operation]
    ,[Begin Time]
    ,[Transaction ID]
    ,[Transaction Name]
    ,[Transaction SID]
    ,SUSER_SNAME([Transaction SID]) as UserWhoIssuedTruncate
FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
WHERE Operation = 'LOP_BEGIN_XACT' and
    [Transaction ID] IN (
        SELECT [Transaction ID]
        FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
        WHERE [Transaction Name] = 'TRUNCATE TABLE'
        )
GO
```

[Click here to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO2R3.png)

[image]

Alternatively, you can run a server side trace or turn on SQL Audit.

Always give minimum permissions (principle of least privilege) to your users.

> Is it possible if I change it to FULL ?

Yes it is (and recovery model should be defined by your business - do you want to have point in time restore? How much data your business can afford  to lose? etc.) You have to start maintaining your T-log by running regular log backups. This will keep your T-log at a sensible size.

**Edited**
Query uses "IN" instead of "=" as multiple results in the sub-query are possible.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid it's not possible to know the last time a table was truncated without setting up something to capture the event upfront.

The default trace does not hold information for `truncate` events and `sys.dm_dm_index_usage_stats` won't help you here either.

Your options are:

1. A trace
2. An Extended Events session
3. An audit (I'm not 100% sure it can capture TRUNCATE events)

As far as your second question is concerned, the recovery model for production databases is usually `FULL`, because restoring the database at a specific point in time is generally speaking a requirement. Databases that contain only data that can be easily and quickly rebuilt from other data sources usually don't need to be restored at a specific point in time, so they often are in the `SIMPLE` recovery model